# Oracle scalar function in WHERE clause leads to poor performance

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I've written a scalar function (`DYNAMIC_DATE`) that converts a text value to a date/time.  For example, `DYANMIC_DATE('T-1')` (T-1 = today minus 1 = 'yesterday') returns `08-AUG-2012 00:00:00`.  It also accepts date strings: `DYNAMIC_DATE('10/10/1974')`.

The function makes use of `CASE` statements to parse the sole parameter and calculate a date relative to `sysdate`.

While it doesn't make use of any table in its schema, it does make use of `TABLE` type to store date-format strings:

```
TYPE VARCHAR_TABLE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
formats VARCHAR_TABLE := VARCHAR_TABLE ('mm/dd/rrrr','mm-dd-rrrr','rrrr/mm/dd','rrrr-mm-dd');
```

When I use the function in the `SELECT` clause, the query returns in < 1 second:

```
SELECT  DYNAMIC_DATE('MB-1') START_DATE, DYNAMIC_DATE('ME-1') END_DATE
FROM    DUAL
```

If I use it against our date dimension table (91311 total records), the query completes in < 1 second:

```
SELECT  count(1)
from    date_dimension
where   calendar_dt between DYNAMIC_DATE('MB-1') and  DYNAMIC_DATE('ME-1')
```

Others, however, are having problems with the function if it is used against a larger table (26,301,317 records):

```
/*
cost: 148,840
records: 151,885
time: ~20 minutes
*/
SELECT  count(1)
FROM    ORDERS ord
WHERE   trunc(ord.ordering_date) between DYNAMIC_DATE('mb-1') and DYNAMIC_DATE('me-1')
```

However, the same query, using 'hard coded' dates, returns fairly rapidly:

```
/*
cost: 144,257
records: 151,885
time: 62 seconds
*/
SELECT  count(1)
FROM    ORDERS ord
WHERE   trunc(ord.ordering_date) between to_date('01-JUL-2012','dd-mon-yyyy') AND to_date('31-JUL-2012','dd-mon-yyyy')
```

The vendor's vanilla installation doesn't include an index on the `ORDERING_DATE` field.

The explain plans for both queries are similar:

with function:
[image: using function]

with hard-coded dates:
[image: hard-coded dates]

- Is the `DYNAMIC_DATE` function being called repeatedly in the `WHERE` clause?
- What else might explain the disparity?

** edit **

A `NONUNIQUE` index was added to ORDERS table.  Both queries execute in < 1 second.  Both plans are the same (approach), but the one with the function is lower cost.

I removed the `DETERMINISTIC` keyword from the function; the query executed in < 1 second.

- Is the issue really with the function or was it related to the table?
- 3 years from now, when this table is even larger, and if I don't include the `DETERMINISTIC` keyword, will query performance suffer?
- Will the `DETERMINISTIC` keyword have any affect on the function's results?  If I run `DYNAMIC_DATE('T-1')` tomorrow, will I get the same results as if I ran it today (08/09/2012)?  If so, this approach won't work.

Comment: If the explain plans are similar, does that imply that they are not identical?  If they are not identical, can you post the two plans?

Comment: The plans are the exact same (meaning steps); only the total cost differs.

Comment: How many records are there in `ORDERS`?

Comment: Is `DYNAMIC_DATE` declared as `DETERMINISTIC`?

Comment: No, it is not declared as `DETERMINISTIC`.  Where would that be specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the steps of the plan are identical, then the total amount of work being done should be identical.  If you trace the session (something simple like `set autotrace on` in SQL*Plus or something more sophisticated like an event 10046 trace), or if you look at `DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT` assuming you have licensed access to the AWR tables, are you seeing (roughly) the same amount of logical I/O and CPU consumption for the two queries?  Is it possible that the difference in runtime you are seeing is the result of the data being cached when you run the second query?

Comment: In my testing, I'm usually executing the query with the function after the hard-coded one.  Wouldn't this eliminate any caching benefits?

Comment: @craig - Are you able to query the AWR tables?  If so, where does `DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT` show the elapsed time difference is between the queries?  Is the difference all due to PL/SQL elapsed time?  Is your function declared `DETERMINISTIC`?

Comment: It is not declared `DETERMINISTIC`.  What does this mean, exactly?  I do have access to the `DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT` table.  Can you recommend a query?

Comment: Adding `DETERMINISTIC` to the function eliminated the performance disparity.  If you add it to your answer and explain its purpose, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the problem isn't with your function. Try creating a function based index on `trunc(ord.ordering_date)` and see the explain plans.

```
 CREATE INDEX ord_date_index ON ord(trunc(ord.ordering_date));
```

Comment: If it makes a difference, I've tried the two queries without the TRUNC() logic.  The results (i.e. performance) are similar.  Does that change your thinking?

Comment: Then I would like to see the function `DYNAMIC_DATE` and see whats going on in there.